# Run test as a step in another test in cucumber

Tags: typescript, testing, cucumber, playwright

Can anyone please tell me how to run one test in another test as a step in Cucumber, Playwright using typescript

Here's the example

```
@testcase1
when something
     {some actions}
then something
     {some actions}
@testcase2
when something
     @testcase1
```

I have been searching for an answer but i cant find id, maybe someone has a better solution than that but kindly remember that my testcase that i want to use as a step has very much steps beneath

Comment: I don't believe this is a behaviour that cucumber intends to support; the feature file is meant to provide a declarative intent of what you're going to test, so allowing it to reference another test like that seems counter to that intent.